# Under extrusion, looking for specific information

Tags: ultimaker-cura, extrusion, monoprice-maker-select

Have a Monoprice maker select with a Micro Swiss hotend, and am using Cura IIIP.

**Edit**: plus [Janbex](http://www.janbex.eu) PLA 1.75mm filament.

Trying to print a [Pi camera mount](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:128617), but am getting (I believe) under extrusion, as seen here.

[image]

My Cura settings are these.

[image]

Does anybody see any obvious problems? What should I try to change?

**Edit**: have played around with different temperatures, and some other settings (eg the filament diameter), but lost track of the reasons. Was following various instructions on web pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filament is `1.75 mm`, but you specified `1.6 mm` in the `Filament` option `Diameter (mm)`.

Furthermore, your layer thickness is very small (`0.06 mm`), why not try `0.20 mm` first; a thicker layer will cause a higher extrusion flow. It could be that the print speed is too high for the low layer size.

Your initial layer `0.3 mm` is also high, the maximum for a `0.4 mm` nozzle.

---

<sub>Why did you change so many parameters? The standard values work pretty well.</sub>

Comment: It worked fine after I changed the diameter to 1.75 and the thickness to 0.2 (initial 0.25).

Comment: side note: Most printers can easily achieve 0.1mm (I rather like it that way), but any lower is hard for many printers.

Comment: @Trish: 0.06 was the standard setting I think, and worked fine for a while with the original extruder.

Comment: FWIW  my AnetA8 runs with 0.4 mm nozzle and 0.06 mm layer just fine (and up to about 1.0 mm layer height for less resolution); with PLA.